# Which graphics driver in the Additional Drivers list should I choose?

Tags: 18.04, nvidia-geforce, gpu-driver, additional-drivers

Please tell me the best option among these options displayed in the screenshot.

[image]

Comment: please check the screen shot by clicking the above highlighted text "additional drivers........"

Comment: The "Best" option is unlikely to be the proper option.  You're using Nouveau currently.  The 'tested' drivers are nvidia-driver-390.  Have you tried switching to nvidia-driver-390 to see if there's any problems caused by the Nouveau drivers?  Also, unless you have issues running the NOuveau driver you probably should just stick with it...

Comment: If not sure what driver is correct, you can look here. Just do not download directly from nVidia, you want version from Ubuntu. https://www.geforce.com/drivers Generally Ubuntu will suggest correct version(s).

Answer (score 1):

Let the built-in ubuntu-drivers program decide automatically which proprietary graphics drivers to install. Open the terminal and type:

```
sudo ubuntu-drivers install   
sudo reboot
```

The install option of ubuntu-drivers installs drivers that are appropriate for automatic installation including their dependencies.